# Grub - How can a new menu.lst file be automatically generated when running 18.04?

Tags: boot, grub2

When on Ubuntu 16.04, if any unintentional edits were made to my /boot/grub/menu.lst file I was able to delete the file, and then run "update-grub" and I was prompted to generate a new file. After upgrading to 18.04, however, it appears that grub gets uninstalled and this command is unavailable (unless choosing to reinstall grub).

Taking this into account, what is now the suggested way of carrying out the above?

Comment: Grub2 doesn't use a `/boot/grub/menu.list` file but uses the configuration file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This is the case for 16.04 and 18.04. I also don't see why upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 should uninstall grub in any way, that's not the case. Did you have an older version of Grub installed in 16.04 before upgrading? That would explain the confusion.

Comment: @mook765 actually, there is a `/boot/grub/menu.lst` file even with grub2.

Comment: @terdon I don't have `/boot/grub/menu.list` in any of my installations, yours might be a left-over from upgrading. https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Changes-from-GRUB-Legacy.html#Changes-from-GRUB-Legacy

Comment: @mook765 yes, you must be right. I checked on another machine and that one didn't have it. I was actually about to write the same basic comment you did but checked just in case and was surprised to find the file! I know I haven't used the `menu.lst` file in several years, not since the switch to grub2 anyway.

Comment: @elliott94 what is the problem if `update-grub` works after choosing to reinstall grub?

Comment: @mook765 You're right - this install was an upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04, and now to 18.04. If this is the case - is there a recommended way of generating a new Grub config file?

Comment: @Hobbyist - There isn't a problem as such - I wasn't aware that the config file format had changed. My question was mainly around how a new config file can be generated (as was possible with the legacy version of Grub).

Comment: @elliott94 Running `sudo update-grub` will generate the configuration file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, this is the file Grub2 uses. If the file already exits, it will be overwritten.